# WordPress Pull Database Info and Display it into a Page

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created some tables on phpmyadmin and I am trying to pull and display those tables in one of my wordpress pages using global $wpdb;

Is there a way someone can help me achieve this? Here is my code:

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['name'];$id=str_replace('_',' ',$name);

global $wpdb;
$res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `agents` WHERE `name`='".$name."'");
foreach ($res as $row) {
  $name = $row->name;
}
?>
```

am I missing something?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You'd probably want to sanitize your input... $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($name)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['name'];$id=str_replace('_',' ',$name);

global $wpdb;
$res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}agents` WHERE `name`='".$name."'");
foreach ($res as $row) {
  $name = $row->name;
}
?>
```

Comment: It's still not displaying anything. I think There may be some conflict somewhere but good thought though.

Comment: echo "SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}agents` WHERE `name`='".$name."'"; try echoing this and try to run printed query manually you will come to know what error is ..

Comment: Very strange, Not pulling anything and no message

Comment: in root directory look for wp-config.php and in that file set wp_debug to true and then try

Comment: I just did that and got the following error: Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in 
/home2/root/public_html/website/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/exec-php.php on line 22

Notice: add_custom_background is deprecated since version 3.4! Use add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args ) instead. 
in /home2/root/public_html/website/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2900

Comment: I did and here is the line from the notice:  `$GLOBALS['g_execphp_manager'] =& new ExecPhp_Manager();`

Comment: and here is the line from functions in Wp_includes: `trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );`

Comment: Use add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args ) instead of the deprecated function

Comment: I am not a PHP Savvy although I know my way very well around WordPress and Codes. If you could copy and paste the corrections for me So I copy and past as well I will greatly appreciate it. Thanks you so much! and Here is the code: `trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );`